# How to extract podcast URLs from XML feed with xsltproc?

Tags: xslt, rss

I wanto to extract URLs from podcast feeds with xsltproc (or any other tool I can use in Bash). There the following two types of XML feeds.

**Type A**

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>
    <title>Podcast</title>
    <item>
        <title>Episode</title>
        <media:content url="http://example.org/example.mp3" fileSize="1234" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

**Type B**

```
<rss>
    <channel>
    <title>Podcast</title>
    <item>
        <title>Episode</title>
        <guid>episode::x</guid>
        <enclosure type="image/jpeg" url="http://example.org/coverart.jpg"/>
        <enclosure type="audio/mpeg" url="http://example.net/audio.mp3"/>
    </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I have the following stylesheet that returns the URLs from type B but not from type A. Can I even mix those two in one stylesheet?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <output method="text"/>
    <template match="/">
        <for-each select = "rss/channel/item/enclosure">
            <value-of select="@url"/><text>&#10;</text>
        </for-each>
        <for-each select = "rss/channel/item/media">
            <value-of select="@url"/><text>&#10;</text>
        </for-each>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Type A** XML, there's a namespace associated with the `<content>` node having alias as `media`. The namespace is not included in the stylesheet. It needs to be included in the stylesheet so that the elements associated with the namespace are accessed correctly.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="media">
```

Inside the template, the `for-each` loop should be `media:content`, (`content` element is missing).

```
<xsl:for-each select="//media:content">
    <xsl:value-of select="@url" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```